# WooCommerce: Out of stock notification issue for a product with low stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, notifications, product, stock

I have set stock for a product to **`1`**. But when I test this setting on front office, trying to buy it, I have this error message:

> 'Sorry, we do not have enough "product name" in stock to fulfill your order right now. Please try again in 60 minutes or edit your cart and try again. We apologise for any inconvenience caused.'

I don't understand why I have this error, because there is **`1`** item in stock for this product.

How to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Stock / Inventory product purposes in WooCommerce:

1) Woocommerce settings > Products *(tab)* > Inventory *(sub-tab)*:

Normally your stock management is enable.

You need to set the **Out Of Stock Threshold** to `0`
You can disable **Low Stock Thresold notifications** too, if needed.

[image]

2) At individual product level (on product pages) > Product data meta box > inventory (tab):

You can "Enable stock management at product level" and have individual settings for a specific product. So you will have to check there too.

Comment: Didn't work for me! In fact, my configs were already like the ones you said above.

Comment: @RangelR.Morais Sorry for you… All this is about settings, so you need to make some tries, and to find out the right working way.

Comment: In fact, it was a bug. Later i found the update to my version on the author's github and this were fixed. Thanks! But now, the itens are not coming back to the stock after the time. Im considering change the plugin.

Comment: The problem came back, and i was not the plugin i have mentioned earlier. But i found the solution, see next!

Comment: @RangelR.Morais Your screenshot should be in english as in this forum everywhere speak and read in english exclusively, and your answer is very unclear, as you should explain everything. My answer was answering WooCommerce version 2.6.x… and it works for WooCommerce 2.6.x.

Comment: When product no stock, notification email send to admin & vendor email id! i add only admin email to inventory section but don't know how vendor also get notification email Do you have any idea ? please advise

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after some digging found that one paypal payment for the product in question is 'pending' that means the person did not have sufficient funds in her paypal account and paypal is waiting to get verification from the bank. The seat will not be released for purchase or show out of stock until paypal secures the funds. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution, but see:

> WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Inventory

And clear this settings like this:
[image: My print is on PTBR]

Like i said, this is not a perfect solution, since it disables one of the many functions of this plugin, but it helps till the wooteam fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to leave blank "Hold Stock (minutes)"